# Scaling images on an mobile site to fit the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Okay, so I'm making a mobile theme to my website, which is based on WordPress. I need to scale the images in articles to fit the screen. Okay, I could do that easily with CSS (width: 100%, height: auto) but that's not working right, because then images which are horizontal would be scaled stupidly.

So let's say the images are sized:

1. 576x432
2. 432x576
3. 100x300

Let's say that the screen resolution is 360x640.

Here's how I wan't the images to scale:

1. 360x270 (same dimension, but scaled down!)
2. 360x480 (same dimension, but scaled down!)
3. 100x300 (not scaled, because 100<360)

With the CSS thing everything would just be scaled to 360xSomething, even the small one which doesn't need scaling. And if screen was like 460x780, number 2 would be scaled up even if not needed!

So here's what I've thought of doing:

1. Go through all images
2. Check if image width > screen width
3. If yes, then scale, if not => skip
4. Profit!

And the problem: I have no idea how :( So any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `max-height:100%;` and `max-width:100%;`

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5DLnK/4/)**

I used a wapper div the size of your example screen (360x640) around the images and you can see that only the wider/heigher images are scaled.

Comment: How do I get to know the screen resolution in CSS?

Comment: @TheDuckFIN as you can see on my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5DLnK/4/) the images adapt only if they are bigger tahn the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
.image-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Apply this class to images.. Should stretch the image on smaller screens :-)

Thank you,
Rahul Patil

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily achieve that.
Instead of `width:100%`, use `max-width:100%`.

Answer (score 0):

To scale any image to browser width, simple idea is to use

```
width:100%;
height:auto
```

see this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/exDLP/)